# For loop, how can i use loop variable outside loop

Tags: python

```
LR = int(raw_input()) 
RPL = []
c1 = []
c2 = []
L1a = [8, 9, 14, 13, 12]
L2a =[9, 12, 14, 10, 8]
OM = [9, 10]
L3a = [26]
L1b = [27, 32, 26]
L2b = [30, 27, 32, 28, 31]
L3b = [31, 30, 26]

def I():
    for i in L1b:
        for j in L2b:
            for k in L3b:
                n = i * j * k
                c1.append(n)
    for i in OM:
        for j in L1a:
            for k in L2a:
                n = i * j * k
                c2.append(n)
def II():
    for i in c1:
        for j in c2:
            x = (i / j) * LR
            RPL.append(x)
```

In my program I need for loop variables i,j,k from 'I' function to print them in my 'II' function to show what combination was used to create x. I tried with two dimensional arrays but it didnt work well. So is there any easy option to work this out?

Comment: ...What? You would need to explain what you want with examples.

Comment: In function I i calculate all possible combinations. In function II i use this combination to calculate value. In example in function I i have 27 from L1b 30 from L2b and 26 from L3b from OM 9, from L1a 9 and from L2a 12.  and i want print it in function II to show that combination 27,30,26 and combination of 9,9,12 was used to calculate x

Comment: Did you use a computer program to generate variable names? You seriously need to consider using some meaningful name even if you are the only person using the code. Somewhere down the line you yourself will get confused.

Comment: I can only think of 2 ways of gettind variables from I to II. Either call I inside II and get it to return  the last i,j,k (you need to store them and return them) or (this is not advice) use a global variable to store i,j,k in to and II can just call that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script I think does what you are trying to do:

```
import operator, itertools

LR = int(raw_input())

L1a = [8, 9, 14, 13, 12]
L2a = [9, 12, 14, 10, 8]
L3a = [26]
L1b = [27, 32, 26]
L2b = [30, 27, 32, 28, 31]
L3b = [31, 30, 26]
OM = [9, 10]

c1 = [(reduce(operator.mul, p), p) for p in itertools.product(L1b, L2b, L3b)]
c2 = [(reduce(operator.mul, p), p) for p in itertools.product(OM, L1a, L2a)]

RPL = [(((p[0][0]) / p[1][0]) * LR, p[0][1], p[1][1])  for p in itertools.product(c1, c2)]

print RPL
```

This displays the following type of results of an `LR` of `10`:

```
[(380, (27, 30, 31), (9, 8, 9)), (290, (27, 30, 31), (9, 8, 12)), (240, (27, 30, 31), (9, 8, 14)), ... etc
```

Each permutation is stored as a tuple with the result of the multiplication. This is then used when calculating your `RPL` value.

You could also format `RPL` as follows, to show which permutations made each result:

```
for rpl, p1, p2 in RPL:
    print "%8d  %15s  %15s" % (rpl, str(p1), str(p2))
```

Giving output in the form:

```
 380     (27, 30, 31)        (9, 8, 9)
 290     (27, 30, 31)       (9, 8, 12)
 240     (27, 30, 31)       (9, 8, 14)
 340     (27, 30, 31)       (9, 8, 10)
 430     (27, 30, 31)        (9, 8, 8)
 340     (27, 30, 31)        (9, 9, 9)
```

The script uses the Python `itertools` module. This provides a `product` function which has the same effect of having multiple nested `for` loops. The result of each iteration gives your values for `i`, `j` and `k`, but as a tuple, e.g. `(27, 30, 31)`.

The `reduce` command can be used to multiply all of the numbers in the list that was returned, by applying the same function to each entry. As you can't write `reduce( * , p)`, you can use Python's `operator` module to provide a function name version for `*`, i.e. `operator.mul`.

The result of this gets wrapped in `()` to make a tuple with two parts, the first is the result of the multiplications and the second part is the permutation that produced it. e.g. `(25110, (27, 30, 31))`.

`c1` is a list holding all of these value. This is called a list comprehension. It is equivalent to a `for` loop with `c1.append()` inside.

Once `c1` and `c2` have been created (I suggest you try and print their values to see what they look like), the script then uses a similar method to calculate all of the RPL values. Each iteration gives `p` which would look like:

```
((25110, (27, 30, 31)), (648, (9, 8, 9)))
```

This is a tuple with two entries `(25110, (27, 30, 31))` and `(648, (9, 8, 9))`. Python can access each value using indexes. So to get the `25110` you would use `p[0][0]` for the first tuple, first part. Or `p[0][1]` to get `(27, 30, 31)`.

The solution script could be converted to not use list comprehensions as follows:

```
c1 = []

for p in itertools.product(L1b, L2b, L3b):
    multiply_all = reduce(operator.mul, p)
    c1.append((multiply_all, p))

c2 = []

for p in itertools.product(OM, L1a, L2a):
    multiply_all = reduce(operator.mul, p)
    c2.append((multiply_all, p))

RPL = []

for p in itertools.product(c1, c2):
    calculation = (p[0][0] / p[1][0]) * LR
    RPL.append((calculation, p[0][1], p[1][1]))
```

Comment: What is `OM` in your script? I had to assume it was just typo for the way you created `c2`

Comment: I like your script but i dont understand anything. Could you write it in more simple way?

Comment: I have added some comments as to how it works, and have also modified it to use your `OM` values. This seems to give the same output as your version now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want i, j and k, store them instead of their product. Instead of `c1.append(n)`, use `c1.append((i, j, k))`.

Then, in `II` would look like this:

```
for (i1, j1, k1) in c1:
    for (i2, j2, k2) in c2:
        i = i1 * j1 * k1
        j = i2 * j2 * k2

        x = (i / j) * LR
        RPL.append(x)
```

A thing you should consider is that you can return two lists from `I` instead of having two global lists. Global variables that are modified are usually a Bad Thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use loop variables outside the loop. Never. Even if language allows that - it is totally confusing and a sign of a bad code structure.

Regarding your question - there are a number of ways to do that. The least involving would be to use a tuple instead of a number in last iteration of `I` (do you have a better names for them?).

```
def I():
    # snip
    n = i * j * k
    c2.append((i, j, k, n))  # double braces is important

def II():
    # snip
    for c1_loop_var in c1:  # note loop variable name changed
        for i, j, k, n in c2:
            x = (c1_loop_var / n) * LR
            # and whatever you need to do with i,j,k
```

As a side note, the snippet you provided does not contain a single variable with a good name, so it's totally not clear to anyone. If you're going to be the only user of this code - up to you, but I would try giving them more sensible names - it's a good practice anyway.

Comment: What about i,j,k used in L1b,L2b,L3b?

Comment: Not true. Python allows using loop variables outside loops. It is often convenient. In a language where you declare variables, you'd declare the loop counter outside the loop, which makes it not confusing at all IMO.

Comment: @IwkoFronc replace c1.append(n) to c1.append((i,j,k,n)) and c1_loop_var to c1_i, c1_j, c1_k, c1_n

Comment: @Joonazan ok, python does allow that, but it doesn't make the idea of using loop var outside the loop better. In my opinion - yours might be different.

Comment: @J0HN  x = (c1_loop_var / n) * LR c1_loop_var replace to  c1_i, c1_j, c1_k, c1_n?